# Data set refresh- failed in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

Has anyone seen the attached error and has any advice on how to fix it? Previously the problem, which occurred a few weeks ago, was resolved after a few refreshes, but not this time.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTcWk.png)

I tried to refresh the dataset connected with report /dashboard.

In addition , when I tried locally to refresh in the POWERBI desktop, got below error:
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.. '.